# Angular prerendering using Google Puppeteer not working

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, puppeteer, prerender

I want to use Google Puppeteer for Pre-rendering(server side rendering) for my Angular 1.4 version.

But i see blank page on http://www.browseo.net/

Following code is used

```
(async() => {
const Browser = require('puppeteer');
    //const browser = new Browser();
    const browser = await Browser.launch({
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Where is your angular code? Moreover, where is your problematic code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any code there where you'd actually navigate the headless browser to anywhere, so try like:

```
// declare var document: any; // Typescript
var document; // JS
async function getPage(url) {
const Browser = require('puppeteer');
    const browser = await Browser.launch({
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    const html = page.evaluate(() => `<html>${document.head.innerHTML}${document.body.innerHTML}</html>`);
    await browser.close();
    return html;
}


getPage('http://www.browseo.net/').then(html => console.log(html));
```

In case you're wondering what `document` is and how that can work, it's because `page.evaluate` runs the function you pass to it, in the context of the headless browser's window, so this way you can reference global variables from there.

Comment: i am using sublime text i get the following error :
`
declare var document: any;
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
`

Comment: Hmm, actually since you don't use Typescript, you probably won't need that line at all. Try removing it or if it doesn't work, replace with just `var document;`

Comment: Yeah `var document` should do it. Sorry about that, forgot not everyone is using TS. :D

Comment: Web page is loading properly but i still get **Navigational timeout** on the server

 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded

Comment: Thanks for your help but i need my webpage to load propely when i check for SEO.
when i check my site http://www.example.com ON **http://www.browseo.net/** 
I just see a blank page with the chat box nothing renders on the screen.

Do i need anything else than google puppeteer.

Comment: Puppeteer is one way. You'll need to prerender all the pages on your site, store the HTML of them somewhere, and make your server serve those instead of the non-rendered index.html with Javascript. So it's not trivial..  There are services that do all this transparently and automatically (like a CDN between your server and the world) take a look at prerender.io for example

Comment: But prerender.io is a paid service.
Can u help me with any source link wherein i can do this process for free and cache pages again when it changes.

Comment: Not trying to be an a-hole here but man there's limits to stuff you can get for free unless you're ready to learn to do it yourself.